# How to update Email Address in Firebase Authentication in Swift 4

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift4

i just want to update authenticate email address of current user. i have tried lot's of solution like updateEmail method of firebase but it not work !! if any one know then please tell me how can i achieved this Thanks in advance !!

[image]

```
@IBAction func btnResetEmailClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let auth = Auth.auth()
        guard let email = self.txtEmailAddress.text ?? auth.currentUser?.email else { return }
        // email that i have to update with current user email
        auth.currentUser?.updateEmail(to: (auth.currentUser?.email)!, completion: { (error) in
            if error == nil{

            }else{
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? As in: what line in that code doesn't do what you expect it to do when you run it in a debugger?

Comment: Yes I debug code ! it going to if loop means it success and now what should I do next !!

Comment: It appears you're updating the email address to the same already existing email address. i.e. change `(to: (auth.currentUser?.email)!` to `(to: (email)!`. For an example, see my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135066/updating-firebase-values-gives-an-error/48138127#48138127) question.

Comment: Okay Thanks I will check and tell you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the email address the user has to be logged in recently i would suggest doing this:

```
var credential: AuthCredential

@IBAction func changeEmail() {
    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        // re authenticate the user
        user.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
            if let error = error {
                // An error happened.
            } else {
                // User re-authenticated.
                user.updateEmail(to: "email") { (error) in
                    // email updated
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: while credential is not initialed user.reauthenticate(with: credential) will crash.

Answer (score 1):

This is effective method to solve it.

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
user?.updateEmail(to: "email") { error in
if error != nil {
    // An error happened
} else {
   // Email updated.
   }
}
```

Comment: What does that mean `enter code here` several times? your answer is somehow wrong.